# Firebase authentication with react and node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I have a full stack application with react frontend and node backend. I want to integrate firebase authentication such that the user gets a jet using firebase and then can use it to interact with the routes only for the authenticated users in the REST API

I am able to log in the user in the frontend and am getting a UID, idToken and Access token.
What is the correct method to go on from here and how do I use these for sending secure requests to my backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) on the backend and use it to [verify ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) coming from the client.

Comment: So I will store the idToken in a cookie, and in every request to the node API, I will send it in the header, verify it in the middleware and then handle the case? Is the accessToken of any use?

Comment: I don't know - do you need anything other than user verification? Usually it's just the ID token that matters.